# Import dlib on Jetson NX got undefined symbol: png_riffle_palette_neon

Tags: gpu, dlib, nvidia-jetson

JetPack version: 4.6

I am trying to use dlib (GPU) on Jetson Xavier NX, following are my steps to install dlib

```
dowload repo: https://github.com/davisking/dlib
cd dlib-master
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1
cmake --build .
cd ..
sudo python3 setup.py install --set USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 --set DLIB_USE_CUDA=1
```

When I run import dlib

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I just figured out it probably caused by the following error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dlib-19.22.99-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg/dlib/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dlib-19.22.99-py3.6-linux-aarch64.egg/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: png_riffle_palette_neon
```

is there any suggestion on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like libpng is missing, to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Then reinstall dlib:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir dlib
```

To check if the installation was successful:

```
python3 -c 'import dlib;print(dlib.__version__)'
```

If there is no tracebacks you are good to go!